# How to save the PyTorch version and the CUDA version to environment variables

Tags: docker, dockerfile, environment-variables, torch

I'm writing a Dockerfile which needs to install different pip wheels, depending on the PyTorch version and the CUDA version installed in the base image:

```
RUN pip install torch-scatter -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-${TORCH}+${CUDA}.html
RUN pip install torch-sparse -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-${TORCH}+${CUDA}.html
```

For this reason, I need to capture these versions **at build time**, into the environment variables `TORCH` and `CUDA`.

I know I could use the `ENV` command in a Dockerfile to assign to environmental variables:

```
ENV TORCH=1.12.0
ENV CUDA=113
```

(note that `CUDA` must not contain any dot, unlike `TORCH`), then build the container. Now, if I log into the running Docker container, I can get these versions from the command line:

```
python -c "import torch; print(torch.__version__)"
>>> 1.12.0
python -c "import torch; print(torch.version.cuda)"
>>> 11.3
```

However, I don't want to hardcode the versions in the Dockerfile, because if I change the base image, the hardcoded values will be wrong, I will try installing the wrong wheels, and installation will fail. I want to find them at build time, and assign them to `TORCH` & `CUDA`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ordinary shell syntax to set environment variables within a `RUN` command, with the limitation that those settings will be lost at the end of that command.  So *within a single `RUN` command* you can use shell command substitution to set the environment variable and use it, but its value will not be available any more after that command.

```bash
# all within a single RUN line
RUN TORCH=$(python -c "import torch; print(torch.__version__)"); \
    CUDA=$(python -c "import torch; print(torch.version.cuda)" | sed 's/\.//g'); \
    pip install torch-scatter -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-${TORCH}+${CUDA}.html; \
    pip install torch-sparse -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-${TORCH}+${CUDA}.html
```